# Get object type based on it's property values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to reduce amount of code and error by introducing static constraints to chat commands.
Commands are described with a name and arguments. Here's what I've got:

```js
type ArgumentTypeName = 'string' | 'number' | 'user';
type CommandArguments<T> = { [k in keyof T]: ArgumentTypeName };
type CommandHandler<T> = (args: T) => void;

type Command<T> = {
  name: string;
  arguments: CommandArguments<T>;
  handler: CommandHandler<T>;
}
```

I can't figure out how to get `T` type from `arguments` of `Command<T>`, so it can correctly influence `handler`.
So far I'm getting a type with correct keys, but all values are `unknown`. Like this:

```js
arguments = { arg1: 'string' }
// handler: (args: { arg1: unknown }) => void
```

I also tried to constraint `arguments`, thinking that if I don't specify T, it will be inferred from `arguments`, but that didnt work:

```js
type ArgumentName<T> = 
  T extends string ? 'string' :
  T extends number ? 'number' :
  T extends User ? 'user' :
  never;

type CommandArguments<T> = { [k in keyof T]: ArgumentName<T[k]> };
type CommandHandler<T> = (args: T) => void;

type Command<T> = {
  name: string;
  arguments: CommandArguments<T>;
  handler: CommandHandler<T>;
}
```

How can I, like, infer-backwards `T` based on its property `CommandArguments<T>`?
So I get `CommandArguments<T>` → `T` → `CommandHandler<T>`?
Or is there a different approach that I didn't think of?

Edit:
Example of code that uses this:

```js
/*
In another file:
  const commands: Command<any>[] = [];
  export function createCommand<T>(cmd: Command<T>) {
    commands.push(cmd);
  }
*/

createCommand({
  name: 'add',
  arguments: {
    a: 'number',
    b: 'number'
  },
  handler: (args) => {
    // (parameter) args: { a: unknown; b: unknown; }
    // Error: Object is of type 'unknown'. ts(2571)
    console.log(args.a + args.b);
  },
});
```

Comment: Please share your `handler` function. I mean the code which using these types

Comment: @captain-yossarian Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To infer `CommandHandler` from `CommandArguments`, we probably don't want to do the opposite, i.e. `ArgumentName<T[k]>` in

```
type CommandArguments<T> = { [k in keyof T]: ArgumentName<T[k]> };
```

Another problem with the above approach is that from the above declaration, `CommandArguments` only constraints the **keys** of `T`, that's why `T`'s properties **value** type are inferred to be just `unknown`.

A straightforward solution is to constraint `arguments`'s type `T` to extends an object of `ArgumentTypeName`, then infer `handler`'s `args` from that type `T`. Here we need to use `T extends CommandArguments` instead of `CommandArguments` in order to capture the actual usage type.

```
declare interface User{};
type ArgumentType<T> =
  T extends 'string' ? string :
  T extends 'number' ? number :
  T extends 'user'   ? User   :
  never;

type ArgumentTypeName = 'string' | 'number' | 'user';
type CommandArguments = { [k: string]: ArgumentTypeName };
type CommandHandler<T> = (args: { [k in keyof T]: ArgumentType<T[k]>}) => void;

type Command<T extends CommandArguments> = {
  name: string;
  arguments: T;
  handler: CommandHandler<T>;
}

const commands: Command<any>[] = [];
export function createCommand<T extends CommandArguments>(cmd: Command<T>) {
  commands.push(cmd);
}

createCommand({
  name: 'add',
  arguments: {
    a: 'number',
    b: 'string',
    c: 'user',
  },
  handler: (args) => {
    // (parameter) args: { a: number; b: string; c: User }
    console.log(args.a.toPrecision(2) + args.b.padStart(30));
  },
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCCqAzhgN4C+A3ALABQqAngA4ICCMA5gK4C2IaAKoxAAePgD54AXhrx4feCAAe6ZMALwA5AVQwUbdfAD88LTuRt4ALmmz5S3qo3JuAIwz6jTrq5iXrcxcoO6hxEMPoyRoQYMr7UMsggAG4YVNQ09EzwrJw8-IIAclA8khomuvoAPo4ubvBVwaHqqRkIAMIA9lxcUCrZ3LyoahLwxPAA2gDWFsbaugC60325qAJMhcUU6YLwHV09wAAS+xAYIuLDABSwbATTo5NIyPATIHTtmLILWez9eUwikzmolIAEpJOJEu1EMBUltMrtuioRLZAmoEfslgMCOcRtZkEUQNMymZUjJrr9BtM+KT4AALY4YabolRHFQnGBnVKkGg0MDtZBaeB8vYqW47TqI4BCHp0URjOYleWpRQMdowVDwTAcZBgVCIflCuBQdDMqX+Oyi8Ui4CYtDYi5gLjAJkS-ZnMHEazCyUEAB0DBCtIdTpBXJ51DARpNrpUF09cXg+J403UUGAwHUABprOTlmL4zF4FAU55vFnrDJnCniXpswmZGAUyE3HWZKRW3SGTBpld2AQwRJxAWYgB6EfwC4MWAE9AwMHXfNF6allLwKszUxschC6ZRHzc+tC-kEdonX0QdpsXs3X1QX2odoABTgYEQBH1yAuACYwQBqIt9r6zj+mmADKqCwKgFwAMwAAwgqG1jtjQoLkEAA)

Comment: Ah, idea of elevating `CommandArguments` to the top somehow missed my mind.Thank you, this works perfectly.